# Css transitions (opacity, transform) stutters in Chrome but not Firefox, Edge etc

Tags: css

I've been unable to solve stuttering in Chrome/Opera when using transitions - e.g. opacity, transform, filter etc.

For simplicity, I will focus on opacity.

Live example here:
[http://www.lydkontoret.dk/index.php?pgId=20&pgName=Lyd+%26+lys](http://www.lydkontoret.dk/index.php?pgId=20&pgName=Lyd%20%26%20lys)

When you click on one of the pictures below the banner, a large version is displayed. I do this by adding a fullscreen div on top of page to prevent access to page elements. The div is faded in via transition on opacity. On top of this div is added further divs that holds the image.

Notice the opacity transition for the fullscreen element when clicking on a picture. On a 24" monitor with browser window maximized, chrome/opera stutters like crazy, while firefox/msie/msedge is reasonably smooth. 
To complicate matters, Chrome/Opera performs ok when browser window is smaller - as rendering engine apparently is able to cope.

I've tried using will-change and translateZ(0) on the various elements involved, but chrome just doesn't care (removing the banner helps a lot - as expected, because the rendering engine then has less to deal with).

Also it's mostly the fade in that stutters. When closing the image display, transition on fullscreen element back to fully transparent often looks acceptable.

I figure my coding is ok, as Firefox etc. do the various transitions nicely. So why the problem with the blink engine used by chrome and opera?

Any thoughts??

Comment: Have you tried it on another computer? I'm currently on a mediocre machine and even full screen (f11) they transition perfectly smoothly for me, even with dev tools open (which on repainted elements can exaggerate slow frame rates)

Comment: Oddly I replicate the issue with Chrome, but Vivaldi, which is based on Chrome, has not stutter. ::shrug::

Comment: @Xhynk:
Will try when I have the opportunity...

Comment: Could be a Chrome Extension eating too many resources then, though I've got a bunch and it ran fine for me